# Hosting on amazon cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, elgg

I am trying to build a social networking site for my current project. I am using Elgg framework for it. The aim of my project is to develop benchmarks for scalable web applications hosted on cloud like AWS etc. We are beginning with amazon. We are concentrating on the concept of big data and social data to be more precise. But before i proceed i wanted to know if i can host my app ( social networking site!) on the cloud. Guidance is required.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. This same question was asked and answered a week ago on the [main Elgg forum](http://community.elgg.org/mod/groups/topicposts.php?topic=794537&group_guid=15815).